# How To Solve Issue Of WordPress Dashboard Shaking Issue?

Tags: wordpress

At WordPress Due to Some Conflictions. My WordPress Dashboard Is Shaking Can Anyone Help To Resolve This issue?

enter link description here][1]
[1]: Link To View Image GIF: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nvzJWeCUiMAnmmkZ14TSmcHcpTfAfXk6/view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just click on the
Admin Dashboard > Posts > Add New or Edit > Screen Shot
Screen option and Disable the "Enable full-height editor" Option. Thanks me later.

[image]

or

Admin Dashboard > Products > Add New or Edit > Screen Shot

Screen option and Disable the "Enable full-height editor" Option. Thanks me later.
[image]